# Changing a field in MYSQL automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users table in a mysql db which stores a users date of birth. Based on the users date of birth I have a field in this table called user_level which is populated with 1 or 2 based on a users age ie 1 for under 13, or 2 for 13 and over.

Is there a way to dynamically change this field from 1 to 2 when a users birthday takes place making them now 13?

Comment: Use a Trigger maybe ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Or you might need some sort of cron job or a daily script which checks for the user birthday and updates the other column accordingly. I am not sure if the triggers will work well for this case actually.

Comment: Yeah I thought a trigger would only be useful if an action was taking place on the table ie update or insert.

Comment: in databases should not be redundant , but I recommend a view or a trigger

Comment: My personal recommendation, you might not want to store the age, why not just query that information using DATE_SUB() when displaying it?

Comment: @McAdam331 I don't think the OP is storing the age but rather a flag based on the age of the user that groups the user. Although that flag itself can be generated as and when needed based on the birthdate field alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mysql scheduler (so long as your mysql version is 5.1.6+).

```
CREATE EVENT birthdayEvent
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2015-05-01 04:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO
    update user set user_level = 2 where user_birthday = date(now() - interval 13 year);
```

Make sure the scheduler is enabled with `set global event_scheduler = on`. Then this event will run every day, at 4am, and update the user levels for everyone whose birthday fell 13 years ago.

Comment: Will this run everyday on its own without any external intervention as long as the server is running ?

Comment: Yes, it will. So long as the scheduler is enabled

Comment: Does it depend on a specific MySQL version or something like that ?

Comment: Great. Thanks ! I didn't know that you could do that with MySQL.

Comment: Neither did I until about two weeks ago. Much nicer than writing scripts and remembering crontab formats

Comment: That is correct. This approach can definitely be used for simple tasks. The more complex ones might still need cron job based on the application requirements.