# How can I execute daily my sql script with PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a sql script updating my database I execute it 3 times a day I need to know how I can make my sql script run daily using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: use the mysql scheduler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992910/changing-a-field-in-mysql-automatically/29993054#29993054

Comment: @PrerakSola the question asks how to do it with mysql, and phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin has no interface to the cron daemon.