# Creating a trigger that would clear an entry once you reach a set date

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

i'm currently working on a school assignment where we have to make a booking site for hotels. And i was wondering if it's possible to make a trigger that would clear the entries in date_arrival and date_depart automatically once you reach the date in date_depart

example of the table in the DB

```
Hotel_ID | Room_ID | Room_Numb | Date_Arrival | Date_Depart |

GH       | SR      | 101       | 22.05.2015   | 30.05.2015  |
```

Picture:

[image: Example]

Comment: check out the mysql event scheduler. [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992910/changing-a-field-in-mysql-automatically/29993054#29993054) for a related answer

Answer (score 0):

A `TRIGGER` can only modify the row it is triggered on, or another table; you might want to look into `EVENT`s if you are using a relatively recent version of MySQL.

Comment: there's a few questions here already about the event scheduler - [here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992910/changing-a-field-in-mysql-automatically/29993054#29993054)